# get_post_meta returns empty array for terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have custom post type of jobs and in this post type I have two custom taxonomies. For job post I selected few terms from both these taxonomies in admin panel but when I tried to access these on front end using `get_post_meta`it is displaying these terms as empty.
I have two taxonomies (city, industry). I am getting city terms like this

```
[_job_city] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )
```

I am getting industry terms like this

```
[_company_industry] => Array
    (
        [0] => s:1:"1";
    )
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: For retrieving terms, we use functions like [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) and not `get_post_meta()`..

Comment: @SallyCJ okay I will try this.

Comment: You can use the [search form](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=terms&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-function) on the WP developer resources site, to find the function that best suites your needs.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried get_the_terms and wp_get_post_terms but both are returning array with error (Invalid taxonomy).

Comment: Can you show your code? And by "For my job post I selected few terms in admin", did you actually mean the standard taxonomy meta box (or terms selector box) on the post/posts edit page?

Comment: @SallyCJ I added more detail in my question.

Comment: Actually I fixed this invalid taxonomy error by using init hook. Previously I was trying to access this without any function.

Comment: (Edited after I read your last comment) So yes, make sure the taxonomies are fully registered before you query their terms. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ yes you are right as I was trying to access these terms before registering these so that is why I had invalid taxonomy error. Instead of get_post_meta now I am using wp_get_post_terms which is working for me. You can add your answer and I will accept your answer if you want. Thank you so much for your time once again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104186/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-wplearner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `get_post_meta` now I am using `wp_get_post_terms` function to access job post terms and it is working for me. It is working correctly for both these taxonomies.